Obtaining UAV flight trajectory from accelerometer and gyro data
I have an accelerometer and gyro scope data logged from several drone flights. I want to obtain flight trajectories from this data. I am considerably new to robotics. But from what I read, I understand that

I can double integrate acceleration information to obtain the positions (trajectory).
This is what is usually called as dead reckoning.
Also, this is very sensitive to IMU noise and using more involves approaches like Kalman filter might better help.

I need to know following:
a. Am I correct with above understanding?
b. Is there any tutorial with say python code explaining both above approaches? (I spent several hours on this, but could not find any !)

Yes you have a correct understanding and general direction of how to design your robot localization system.

Your three statements are correct. But I would like to add a comment to the third point. Yes, a Kalman filter, if set-up correctly, will give better results compared to dead reckoning. However, the dynamical model, given only accelerometer and gyro sensor data, is not fully observable, which means that a Kalman filter or any other algorithm will never be able to remove the drift in position. This drift might be low enough, such that it still yields sufficiently accurate position estimates (over short enough time scales) for many applications, but this limitation is something that one has to keep in mind.
